# Something is turning my lambda function into def function when I run, how do i solve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using **Sublime Text** as my editor with **Python 3**.

Whenever I tried to run my lambda code, it changed into a def function.

This is before

```
add_one = lambda x:x + 1
print(add_one)
```

After

```
def add_one(x): return x + 1
print(add_one)
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about your question?

Comment: Something doesnt sound right in this question

Answer (score 2):

You must have some kind of a linter plug-in in your IDE/command line that automatically changes code to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard.

Disable it.

Comment: May I know where to disable it? I have been searching inside my Sublime Text setting.